# Visual Graph in Google Colab

Tags: charts, graphics, stock

Can anyone help me write this code or recommend how to do it. I tried it with Google Colab but the result was not really good.

https://www.tiktok.com/@axlsacs/video/7269849218997669152 or https://www.tiktok.com/@axlsacs/video/7239445775686569243

I also tried a bit with ChatGpt but I can't get the result I want.

I would be very grateful for your help. I will gladly accept any tips.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.